# VBA Update module every minute

Tags: vba, excel

i have this vba code. i want that this module refresh every one minute and change the value of cell.

i tried with `Application.Volatile` , but its not help. 
when i click CTRL+ALT+F9 its work.

thank you.

```
Function CryptoQuote()
Dim strURL As String, strCSV As String
strURL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD"
Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
http.Open "GET", strURL, False
http.send
strCSV = http.responsetext
CryptoQuote = Val(onlydigits(strCSV))
Set http = Nothing

End Function


Function onlydigits(s As String) As String

Dim retval As String
Dim i As Integer
retval = ""
For i = 1 To Len(s)
If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Or Mid(s, i, 1) = "." Then
retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
End If
Next
onlydigits = retval
End Function
```

Comment: I suppose, you are calling CryptoQuote as a UDF (user defined function), you set the Formula of a Cell, e.g. Sheet1!A1 to =CryptoQuote(). Is this correct? UDFs have some limitations compared to normal Subs.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z91TP2TFxc-QnDuDTu4rUzK7dBuTVIsa/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnTime function provided for VBA. (lots of info on this online). Example:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "my_Procedure"
```

will run code every minute.

Comment: i added this to CryptoQuote and change and its still didnt work.

Comment: Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CryptoQuote"

Comment: are you sure it didn't work? Did you get an error? You have to run the code once to trigger the ontime function.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z91TP2TFxc-QnDuDTu4rUzK7dBuTVIsa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, it occurs to me: ontime may not work in a function. Put it in a sub.

Comment: where? i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code because a UDF is not appropriate for this problem:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CryptoQuote()
    Debug.Print Now & " CryptoQuote called" ' In case the value does not change, we will know if it is because this Sub is not called again or because cryptocompare.com sent the same answer
    Dim strURL As String: strURL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD"
    Dim http As Object: Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.send
    Dim strCSV As String: strCSV = http.responsetext
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Val(onlydigits(strCSV)) ' Change this to refer to the cell where you would like to see the value
    Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "CryptoQuote"
End Sub

Function onlydigits(s As String) As String
    Dim retval As String: retval = ""
    Dim i As Integer: For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Or Mid(s, i, 1) = "." Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    onlydigits = retval
End Function
```

If you run CryptoQuote once, it will update the value continuously.

To start the updating automatically after opening the workbook, add this to the ThisWorkbook module (not to Module1, which is usually you insert your code but locate Microsoft Excel Objects / ThisWorkbook on the left side of your VBA screen):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CryptoQuote
End Sub
```

Comment: i want call in cell to function, not via vba

Comment: The closest thing may be using your UDF + calling a sub repeatedly (similarly to my solution) to recalculate that cell.